# Column-Size on GtkTreeViews

Tags: gtk, gnome, glade, gtktreeview

How can I set the horizontal size of a specific column on a GtkTreeView? I have 4 columns on my TreeView and the last one expands on the rest of the free space. How can I set the first or second column to be expanded on the free space to set a fixed width on all columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `gtk_tree_view_get_column` to get the nth column of a treeview and then use `gtk_tree_view_column_set_sizing` with `GTK_TREE_VIEW_COLUMN_FIXED` on it.

You can also tell columns to expand via `gtk_tree_view_column_set_expand`. To quote the [docs](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/unstable/GtkTreeViewColumn.html):

> Sets the column to take available extra space. This space is shared equally amongst all columns that have the expand set to TRUE. If no column has this option set, then the last column gets all extra space. By default, every column is created with this FALSE.

Answer (score 2):

**Sample for Ruby:**

```ruby
col = Gtk::TreeViewColumn.new("Headline", renderer, :text => 1)
col.expand = true # Expands the column

col.sizing = Gtk::TreeViewColumn::FIXED # Sets the column on a fixed width
col.min_width = 150
```